# Is it bad practice to use production code in the Arrange phase of a test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

**When writing tests in an Arrange-Act-Assert pattern, is it okay to use production code in the arrange phase to put the SUT in a certain state?**

#### Context

I have created a service for handling backups of a database in an SQL Server instance. I want to test this service, specifically the `RestoreFromBackup` method.
The unit test I want to write is `RestoreBackup_BackupExists_NoExceptionThrown`; if a backup exists and the service is asked to restore the database from that backup, there should be no exceptions thrown as a result.

When the test starts, there exists no backup to restore the database from, I need to create it in the Arrange phase of the test. I would like to put only the `RestoreFromBackup` method under test, so I've essentially copied the `CreateBackup` method from the service to the test project and I've used that to create the backup.

Snippet of my test project:

```
// _dataAccessService is the service I'm testing.
// LocalHelpers is a static helper class with some methods to use only in tests, 
// but they're essentially all copies of methods in _dataAccessService.

[Test]
public void RestoreBackup_BackupExists_NoExceptionThrown()
{
    // Arrange
    string backupName = $"{LocalHelpers.GenerateDatabaseBackupName()}.bak";
    LocalHelpers.CreateDatabaseBackup(backupName);

    // Act
    TestDelegate createBackupAction = () => _dataAccessService.RestoreFromBackup(backupName);

    // Assert
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(createBackupAction);
}


private static class LocalHelpers
{
    public static string GenerateDatabaseBackupName(string? connectionString = null)
    {
        // Generate a unique name like "database_guid.newguid().bak".
        // Pretty much copy of production code.
    }

    public static string CreateDatabaseBackup(string backupName, string? connectionString = null)
    {
        // Creates a full database backup of a database in SQL Server's DATA folder.
        // Pretty much copy of production code.
    }
}
```

This feels kind of silly to copy the code, but I'm hesitant to put the "real" method for creating a backup in the test, since then a unit test for **Restore** could fail because the **Create** method breaks in the future when refactoring or whatever.

How should I approach this?

Comment: If you can, use a pre-production environment: a copy of the production environment for test purposes. Another way may be add the new production code (the CreateDatabaseBackup method) in a way that don't affect to production code and allow you try a test. For example, create a CreateDatabaseBackup2 method. This is a very concrete case, that occurs very few times.

Comment: @Victor All the tests are ran against a localhost test database on each dev's machine, I'm just wary of the principle of using the code intended for production to arrange the state of the database (creating the backup) for what is intended to be a unit test. But the alternative is essentially copying the code to the testing project, which also feels kind of pointless (?) and smells like an anti-pattern to me... Or maybe there is a better approach altogether I'm not seeing.